# pyqt gui not showing

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

i am trying out pyQT and followed a tutorial to get startet. I am using Spyder on Win7 64 bit and qt4. Everythinginstalled with spyder. I build a GUI with QTDesigner and made a .py file. I am now trying to start the gui as the tutorial says. I get no errors but the code just finishes and nothing shows up.

This is the code i use:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

from qtTestController import Ui_Form

if __name__ == "main":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.show()
    app.setMainWidget(ui)
    app.exec_loop()
```

If i start it a second time the console says "Reloaded modules: qtTestController"
But still nothing happens. Am I missing anything?

Comment: could you paste the content of `Ui_Form`?

Comment: Would be helpful to link to tutorial.